# Get descending key list of correlation

Tags: python, list, dataframe, correlation

I try to get the name of the top 5 highest correlation score with the column `'price'`.

This is my code:

```
ls = list(df.corrwith(df['price']))
ls.sort(reverse=True)
ls[0:5]
```

The output:

```
[0.9999999999999999,
 0.31555576200285607,
 0.29866047751549785,
 0.2731839437705133,
 0.2673960209310168]
```

If I run this code:

```
df[df.columns[1:]].corr()['price']
```

I will get the output like this:

```
host_since                                     -0.047803
host_response_rate                              0.077262
host_is_superhost                              -0.020062
host_total_listings_count                       0.116733
host_has_profile_pic                           -0.002491
host_identity_verified                         -0.041795
...
```

Is there any way to get the name of the top 5?

Comment: df.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=False) did you tried this to sort values?

Comment: @SahilDesai It needs to modify a bit to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution with the help of @SahilDesai's comment:

```
df[df.columns[1:]].corr()['price'].sort_values(ascending=False)[:6]
```

The output:

```
price           1.000000
accommodates    0.315556
bedrooms        0.298660
cleaning_fee    0.273184
beds            0.267396
bathrooms       0.262596
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = df[df.columns[1:]].corr()['price']

temp.sort_values(by='NameOfTheColumn', ascending=False)

temp.index.values.tolist()[:5]
```

I think this should work.